# mapping bad matches to other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a pandas df where I've already matched the name to the ID, but there are some IDs that don't have a name. For those, I want to go back to the mapping file and search the 'alternative_ID_list' column and see if there is a match with a corresponding name.

```
current df
     name   ID  
0     joe  USER1    
3    mary  USER2    
5  USER3    USER3    
8  USER4    USER4    
9  USER5    USER5    
9  USER6    USER6    


 bad_matches=[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

```
mapping_df =
     name   ID   alternative_ID_list
0     joe  USER1        USER213.32
3    mary  USER2        USER643.11
5     sam  USER98        USER31.5
7    jack  USER992      USER4.2
8    rick  USER902      USER5.6, USER321.1
9    john  USER979      USER6.8, USER987.9
10   jay   USER980      USER479.2, USER989.0

#use mapping_df to find the bad_match_IDs (take the first match found if multiple rows for one bad_match_id)
```

```
desired 

     name   ID  
0    joe     USER1    
3    mary    USER2    
5    USER3    USER3    
7    jack    USER4    
8    rick    USER5    
9    john    USER6
```

Comment: Are correct ID for rick and john in output?

Comment: Yes, I think I messed that up. I just made edits to the post! Thanks for the catch!

Comment: answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

First split column `alternative_ID_list` with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), convert to integer and filter by `bad_matches` for possible match by original DataFrame by [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join, last set same indices and replace matched rows in [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df1 = (mapping_df.assign(alternative_ID_list=mapping_df.alternative_ID_list.str.split(', '))
                 .explode('alternative_ID_list')
                 .astype({'alternative_ID_list':int})
                 .drop_duplicates('alternative_ID_list')
                 .loc[lambda x: x['alternative_ID_list'].isin(bad_matches)])

print (df1)
   name   ID  alternative_ID_list
7  jack  992                  379
8  rick  902                  579
9  john  979                  479

f = lambda x: x.strip('_')
df1 = df.merge(df1, 
               left_on='ID', 
               right_on='alternative_ID_list', 
               how='left', 
               suffixes=('','_'))[['name_','ID_']].rename(columns=f)


df = df1.set_index(df.index).fillna(df).astype({'ID':int})
print (df)
     name   ID
0     joe  123
3    mary  342
5  ID/214  214
8    jack  992
9    rick  902
9    john  979
```

EDIT: Because replaced only column `name` solution is simplify by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
mapping = [str(x) for x in bad_matches]

df1 = (mapping_df.assign(alternative_ID_list=mapping_df.alternative_ID_list.str.split(', '))
                 .explode('alternative_ID_list')
                 .assign(alternative_ID_list = lambda x: x.alternative_ID_list.str.split('.').str[0])
                 .drop_duplicates('alternative_ID_list')
                 .loc[lambda x: x['alternative_ID_list'].str.extract('(\d+)$', expand=False).isin(mapping)]
                 )

print (df1)
   name       ID alternative_ID_list
7  jack  USER992               USER4
8  rick  USER902               USER5
9  john  USER979               USER6

df['name'] = df['ID'].map(df1.set_index('alternative_ID_list')['name']).fillna(df['name'])
print (df)
    name     ID
0    joe  USER1
3   mary  USER2
5  USER3  USER3
8   jack  USER4
9   rick  USER5
9   john  USER6
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just realized my alternative_ID_list column is a string with a 'USER' prefix and it has decimals included as well. I just updated my post to reflect this. Due to this, the code doesn't work for me.

Comment: @youtube - answer was edited.